# Postgres SQL Recursive Query to fill in values based on 2 columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, recursive-query

I have a Postgres table that looks like this:

[image]

These are team pre game and post game ratings where the post game ratings are based on the pregame rating and some additional metrics not shown (score, margin of victory, etc). It contains 2 rows per game (team and opponent flipped) and the game_num column is the running count of games for the team. My goal is to fill in the pre_rating and opponent_pre_rating column with their respective previous post game ratings. So the next 2 rows would look like below:

[image]

I can get the previous rating for the team, but I'm not sure how to go about getting it for the opponent.

Here is my code so far and the current results

```
WITH RECURSIVE ratings AS (
         select r.gameday,
r.game_num,
r.team,
r.opponent,
cast(r.pre_rating as float),
cast(r.opponent_pre_rating as float),
r.post_rating,
r.opponent_post_rating
         from nfl.team_rtgs r
          WHERE r.game_num = 1
        UNION
         SELECT r2.gameday,
r2.game_num,
r2.team,
r2.opponent,
ratings_1.post_rating as pre_rating,
r2.opponent_post_rating as pre_rating,
r2.post_rating,
r2.opponent_post_rating
         from nfl.team_rtgs r2
             JOIN ratings ratings_1 ON (r2.team = ratings_1.team AND r2.game_num = (ratings_1.game_num + 1)))
             select * from ratings
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post your input or expected output as images

Comment: No recursion needed. Lag window functions, one partitioned by team and another partitioned by opponent...

Comment: @ChrisMaurer That won't work. The post_rating and opponent_post_rating are dynamically updated each row using other teams rating.

Comment: *The post_rating and opponent_post_rating are dynamically updated* what make you so confident that lag cannot access dynamic values? e.g. use a cte or derived table

Comment: Quoting site [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc**.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: @PaulMaxwell I'm pretty confident since the post game ratings reference both of the pre game ratings, which depend on the previous games post game ratings, etc. The only rows with values in the table are the team's first game. Would love to know how a lag function could work though.